# On iPhone Objective C, How do you catch the event of a row in a table being selected?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a data table filled with text in each table row.  How do I attach to the event for the row being selected and know which row was selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object that is the `UITableViewDelegate` for your `UITableView` (usually the view controller that owns the table view) just needs to implement the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method. You can get the column and row from the parameter passed in. Be sure to conform to the Apple HIG and deselect the row in this method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    // do something here

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this is also the right place to deselect rows. Too many people miss that.

Answer (score 1):

Your UITableViewDelegate should implement the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` which will be called whenever a row is selected

You can get the section and row that were selected form the indexPath passed into the method with

```
[indexPath row];
[indexPath section];
```

See more under the [UITableViewDelegate protocol reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)